# Math Blogging - what is a decent set up?

Tags: technology-in-education, software

I hope this question is not deemed off-topic, but I cannot think of a more appropriate place to ask it (few tech sites care about support for MathJax and $\LaTeX$), and I think that blogging about mathematical topics is certainly part of mathematical education viewed in the broad sense.

Anyway, I currently have an almost-dormant blog on wordpress.com, and I would like to reinvigorate it and post more frequently. However I have realised that Wordpress itself is hampering me, largely because of its primitive support for $\LaTeX$; every expression has to be between non-standard delimiters and is then replaced by an image which is usually the wrong size and aligned incorrectly.
So this results in tediously writing not-very-reusable source-text that is rendered into ugly output - basically a lose-lose-lose situation.

So really I need to use something that produces MathJax, and in addition it would be better if I could write once and render to either HTML or $\LaTeX$, which seems to limit the field to various Markdown editors. The StackEdit online editor is extremely good, produces output containing MathJax tags, and has a mechanism for direct "Publish to Wordpress". Almost perfect, except that it doesn't work properly for $\TeX$ - it just passes through the marked-up MathJax constructs which don't work on Wordpress. (It would work on a self-hosted Wordpress, where you can add your own Javascript, but my life is too short to get back into self-hosting.)

Anyway, I had better finish with an actual question:

> What is the best way to write mathematical content, preferably using
>   Markdown for formatting, and have the resulting content appear online,
>   with the mathematics rendered in MathJax?

Comment: Do the remarks at Terry Tao's [**blog**](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/about/) help at all? Specifically, those in the penultimate paragraph of the aforelinked (and, perhaps, some of the comments...).

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I had forgotten about that source, but in fact I tried the latex2wp program when I first started, and it does ease the pain somewhat by translating the LaTeX for Wordpress. But the poor rendering and mis-sizing is still there. Terry's blog is so content-dense that people are more willing to work hard at reading it!

Comment: It's trivial to include mathjax in any web page. At the top of your page, you put in a script tag that loads some javascript from mathjax.org. Then in the body of the page you write your math, surrounded by double dollar signs.

Comment: @Ben Unfortunately Wordpress (the hosted one) disables any JavaScript, so that is only possible in the self-hosted version, which I don't want to use, due to the difficulty of configuring and managing it.

Comment: With Wordpress.com, you are flat out of luck. With self-hosted blog platform, anything is possible. With third-party hosted blogs, [this is a good resource](http://checkmyworking.com/2012/01/how-to-get-beautifully-typeset-maths-on-your-blog/), but can use some updating. In particular with regards to blogger/blogspot: the general idea is simple: just put the incantation to MathJax somewhere on your page. While Google changes the way to configure pages every now and then, [people always seem to find the correct spot](http://astro-learned.blogspot.ch/2015/01/mathjax-on-blogger.html).

Comment: You might write your own markdown2html converter...

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [Jetpack Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/)

[From this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76502/is-there-any-mathematical-blog-support-latex)

> By 'supporting LaTeX', many people mean 'supporting the use of TeX-like input for mathematical symbols'. That's not the same thing: support LaTeX proper requires a TeX system, supporting just a small subset does not.
>
> Taking WordPress as an example, both TeX-like input and proper LaTeX support are available. By far the most straight-forward way here is to use a plugin to load the appropriate code from elsewhere. MathJax is the technology that is used for example on other StackExchange sites for TeX-like input, and it's available for WordPress using the JetPack plugin. This plugin makes use of the WordPress.com MathJax support.

Also as a commenter pointed out you could use MathJax and while Wordpress disables JavaScript you could use the [Simple MathJax](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-mathjax/)  plugin to load it.
The above post shows an example, the second answer I believe, of how to incorporate the Mathjax cdn and script into your file.

Comment: Unfortunately, Jetpack is a plugin for wordpress.org users (i.e. the self-hosted ones) to get acess to the wordpress.com (i.e the hosted ones) features, not the other way round.  I am only too well aware that it is horribly confusing!

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that, I am sorry!  Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

MathJax seems to work well in Blogger, although this simple example doesn't irrefutably prove that:
http://fivetriangles.blogspot.com/2014/07/171-fraction-redistribution.html

Comment: It seems you created a second unregistered account. If you want the accounts to be merged, you can follow the instructions at http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts (If you want to keep separate accounts for whatever reason this is fine too.)